# How do I find the proportion of 2 different sub groups within one group?

Tags: statistics, percentages

I am trying to find the proportion of nhl 2k (video game) players that play more than 3 games or play on playstation. 40% of players use xbox, 50% use playstation, and 10% use pc. Of those who play on xbox, 60% play more than 3 games. Of those who play on playstation, 15% play more than 3 games. Of those who play on pc, 0% play more than 3 games.

What proportion of players play more than 3 games OR play on playstation?

I'm not sure if I am supposed to add these 2 proportions together and if my math is correct:

Probability of players play on XBOX = 0.4

Probability of players play on Playstation = 0.5

Probability of players play on pc = 0.1

Probability of players play more than 3 games on XBOX = 0.6

Probability of players play more than 3 games on Playstation = 0.15

Probability of players play more than 3 games on pc = 0.0

Probability of players play more than 3 games = 0.4 * 0.6 + 0.5 * 0.15 = 0.315

So 0.315 proportion of players play more than 3 games.

proportion of players who play on playstation = 0.5 * 0.315 = 0.1575

Should I be adding the probability of players that play more than 3 games to the proportion of players that play on playstation?

Comment: An idea, you may wish to supplement this exercise by looking at data on what are the most popular games now being played and the preferential platform (PlayStation, XBox,...) to execute the game.  Shifts in game preference over time, may be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, some semantical notes. You state 'Probability of players play more than 3 games on XBOX = 0.6' which I am taking to mean 'Probability that a player plays more than three games on XBOX = 0.6' or 'Proportion of players that play more than three games on XBOX = 0.6'. Both of these are not correct. It would be correct to say 'Proportion of XBOX players that play more than three games = 0.6' or 'Probability that a player plays more than three games GIVEN that they play on XBOX = 0.6'. The key difference is the conditionality. The problem is saying that OF THE 40% that play XBOX, 60% play more than three games. This means that 'Probability that a player plays more than three games on XBOX' or 'Proportion of players that play more than three games on XBOX' is 0.4$\cdot$0.6 = 0.24. The same goes for your statements about Playstation and Other. You seem to understand this even if your statements are incorrect because you correctly calculate 'Probability that a player plays more than three games' to be 0.4$\cdot$0.6 + 0.5$\cdot$0.15 + 0.1$\cdot$0 = 0.315. I am confused by your last calculation. I don't know  of any reason you would multiply those two figures together. You state that the problem asks for the probability that a player plays Playstation OR more than three games. To calculate this you should use the following formula:
$$P(A\text{ or }B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\text{ and }B)$$
Here we are looking to calculate $P(\text{plays Playstation or plays more than three games})$ so our formula tells us this is
$$P(\text{plays Playstation})+P(\text{plays more than three games})-P(\text{plays Playstation and plays more than three games})$$
We are given that,
$$P(\text{plays Playstation})=0.5$$
And we computed,
$$P(\text{plays Playstation and plays more than three games})=0.5\cdot0.15=0.075$$
$$P(\text{plays more than three games})=0.315$$
Therefore
$$P(\text{plays Playstation or plays more than three games})=0.5+0.315-0.075=0.74$$
which is our answer.

Comment: This looks good, however, I think you meant that the probability of a person to play playstation is 0.5? 50 percent of players are on playstation.

Comment: yes you are correct I will fix this